# How to handle NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification when store locations are identical

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, nspersistentstore

I'm using Core Data + iCloud and getting quite a few NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotifications, wherein the URL of the old and new stores are the same.  I'm only using one device, and it will happen several times while running my app.

Why is it giving these notifications if the store URLs haven't changed, and the device is the only one persisting data to the store?  Can these notifications be ignored when the old and new URLs are the same?

Here is the contents of the userInfo dictionary for the notification:

```
NSConcreteNotification 0x17a5f6b0 {name = NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification; object = <NSPersistentStoreCoordinator: 0x167e05c0>; userInfo = {
NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeKey = 4;
added =     (
    "<NSSQLCore: 0x1787bcf0> (URL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8D9D2E83-DCD6-427B-BF5B-371D6DFD1999/Documents/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/mobile~38BB3D02-34D8-4E44-BCBE-B3ACC4FFA2DC/QatQiGameData3/8FD336B2-35D5-4D5F-8B06-415C7CA523CB/store/qatqi.sqlite)"
);
removed =     (
    "<NSSQLCore: 0x1787bcf0> (URL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8D9D2E83-DCD6-427B-BF5B-371D6DFD1999/Documents/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/mobile~38BB3D02-34D8-4E44-BCBE-B3ACC4FFA2DC/QatQiGameData3/8FD336B2-35D5-4D5F-8B06-415C7CA523CB/store/qatqi.sqlite)"
);
```

}}

Answer (score 1):

The number '4' corresponds to "NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionType.InitialImportCompleted". Apple's documentation states:

> This value indicates that the Core Data integration has finished building a store file that is consistent with the contents of the iCloud account, and is ready to replace the fallback store with that file.

The fallback store and the ubiquity (iCloud) store do indeed have the same URL, so the URL does not change. If your displayed data is updating properly on import, then yes you can ignore these notifications. Otherwise, you might want to update the data you are displaying.